# counter value doubled inside \input if \currfilebase present

Tags: counters, input, currfile

Using the package [`currfile`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/currfile?lang=en):

```tex
\setcounter{foo}{\inputlineno}%
\def\barfile{.aux/\currfilebase\thefoo.bar}%
\def\texfile{.aux/\currfilebase\thefoo.tex}%
% ...
\input{\texfile}
```

then the counter value is doubled:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `.aux/filename363363.tex' not found.
```

When `\texfile` contains only `\fname` or only `\thefoo`, I do not see any repetition. Also, using the package [`fink`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fink) and `\def\fname{\finkfile}`, no issues arise.

Minimal working example:

Create a main file containing:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile}
\newcounter{counter}
\setcounter{counter}{0}
\begin{document}
    \def\texfile{\currfilebase\thecounter.tex}
    \input{a_main0.tex}
    \input{\texfile}
\end{document}
```

and another file called `a_main0.tex`. Typesetting raises the error:

```
...
(./a_main.aux) (./a_main0.tex)
! LaTeX Error: File `a_main00.tex' not found.
```

Clearly, the file `a_main0.tex` is found by `\input`, but not when the file name is given using `\texfile`, because the character "0" gets duplicated.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `\def\texfile{\currfilebase\thecounter.tex}` is evaluated in the second `\input{\texfile}` call, but the current input file is `a_main0` since `\currfilebase` switches its content to that name at the moment of `\input`, so `\texfile` expands to `a_main00.tex`.

One possible solution is to use `\edef\textfile`, i.e. expanded definition, so `\currentfilebase` is not contained as macro any longer but its value at the time of definition.

`a_main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile}
\newcounter{counter}
\setcounter{counter}{0}
\begin{document}
    \edef\texfile{\currfilebase\thecounter.tex}
    \input{a_main0.tex}
    \input{\texfile}
\end{document}
```

`a_main0.tex` just contains the line

```
\section{Foo from the file with the 0 suffix}
```

I neither recommend underscores in graphics files name (even with `currfile` usage) however (which is not the case here) nor a counter named `counter` ;-)

Comment: What do you have against underscores in file names? I use them all the time...

Comment: @clemens: `in graphics files name` was missing ... thanks

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. Indeed, this case is about including LaTeX files, not in any way associated to graphics files. I should note that I have been using underscores in graphics file names for 8 years now, without any problems (not with such a use case though). For example, in a command named [`\includesvg`](https://github.com/johnyf/latex_packages/blob/101de8e6ab9e87e344b2f1ed6148b06207be9b11/mycommands.sty#L222). I agree about variable naming, the original code has a reasonable name, I chose `counter` for the MWE.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis: You're welcome. Happy TeXing